# Convering consumer of a function to Stream JavaRdd

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

How to process stream of data after consumer applyMapping ? Or process by pack of 1000?

```
private JavaRDD<TracingOdsProjection> enrichWithExternalData(JavaRDD<ExternalDto<T>> rdd) {
    return rdd.flatMap(rec -> {
        List<Dto> res = new ArrayList<>();
        new Library().applyMapping(dto -> res.add(dto));

        return res.iterator();
    });
}
```

I tried rdd.foreach or rdd.foreachPartition collect by 1000 and then sparkContext.parallelize(res).

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(jssc.sparkContext().getConf()).getOrCreate();
try (final JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext())) {
 final JavaRDD<TracingOdsProjection> packOfMappingsJRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(res);
   } catch (Exception e) {
 log.error("On create or useing spark context: ", e);
   }
```

But got task not serializable for JavaSparkContext. when call jssc.sparkContext()

I can't collect into one Arraylist after applyMapping(..) Because it is too huge.

Answer (score 0):

new Library() must implement Iterator, Iterable interfaces.
on next - return new element.

DO NOT use "`res.add(dto)`"! USE iterator instead!